# Azure Search with multiple indexes

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

I need to enable full text & faceted search for a service that stores each customer data in a separate Azure SQL database. Each database in turn stores customer's multiple projects data. Each database can contain n number of projects. Each customer's project's data is accessed as a isolated data repository. Therefore, I need search and facets to be limited to each project's data. Since Azure search supports finite number of Indexes, I am not sure how to best leverage it in my scenario? Moreover, searchable data across projects will have different set of information that needs to be searched. Therefore, columns in Index will vary from project to project in each database.

How to best address this problem through Azure search?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Design patterns for multitenant SaaS applications and Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-modeling-multitenant-saas-applications). In particular, in some cases you can share an index across tenants and use filters to isolate data - see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-modeling-multitenant-saas-applications#achieving-even-finer-granularity). The drawback of this approach is that sharing data across tenants can affect search relevance (since term frequency / document frequency are scoped to an index), but in many scenarios this is acceptable.